# What is the temperature at steering rack?

Tags: steering

What is the **average temperature of air around steering rack**? Can it be greater than 70  C ? Actually I have to put a sensor over there whose threshold temperature of working is 75  C.

Comment: Are you testing the temp of the rack itself, or just the ambient temp where rack is located?

Comment: ambient temperature of air around rack.

Comment: Considering a steering rack's position in a vehicle (low mounted, below the engine, behind the radiator, in open air), I would bet this area is only going to be slightly warmer than ambient air temperature. There will be some air flow from the radiator hitting this area, but it will be mixed from air coming from under the car. I would say, you could try your temperature sensor and doubt you're going to see temp above the 70C you are asking about. It would have to be a hot day on hot pavement to exceed this in my approximation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you ought to be designing for **average** temperature--I think you're more looking for a **peak** temperature under expected conditions for your application.

Depending on atmospheric and driving conditions, the temperature could easily exceed 75 C (stuck in traffic in the summer, for example).

Many types of automotive wiring are [rated to 80-125 C](http://www.awcwire.com/faq-automotive-wire.aspx), you might use this as a reference point for suitability.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably measure the temperature of the power steering fluid reservoir as a ballpark idea; that fluid is pumped through the rack and likely keeps it within 10deg.